# Replicate Figure w/out Inserting New Entry in List of Figures

Tags: floats, table-of-contents, captions

I would like to replicate a figure in Chapter 3 within Chapter 6 such that the figure is displayed and optionally, it has the caption and Figure number of the figure in Chapter 3. If that is not possible, I would like to remove its entry from the List of Figures so that 2 of the same figures are not present.

For the latter I was able to find this: [Removing captions](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=5298) but I suspect it will add the entry to the list of Figures. Is this achievable? Secondly, is this the preferred way of performing a replication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend to use the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. It provides a command `\caption*` which produces a caption without an entry in the list of figures.

Further I guess you probably don't like to number the figure, this is possible with `\caption*` as well. That's because a new and different number 6.x looks as odd as repeating the number 3.x within chapter 6.

Finally, I would use a reference to 3.x instead of replicating the picture.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. As you said, referencing to the previous image makes more sense.

Comment: I misunderstood your last comment; to justify my need of replicating the image I should say that I am actually referring to an example given in Chapter 3. Therefore, it really helps to replicate the image. Further, I was able to perform this: "\caption*{Figure \ref{fig:CH3Fig}: ...}", giving the correct Figure number. This does not add an entry to the List of Figures. I am not sure if this will be approved but this looks good for now. Thanks again.

Comment: @NecArn: Fine! The remark was a general thought, you know best what suits your document.